# Why hexadecimal is not case sensitive in Java?

Tags: java, hex, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

If Java is a case-sensitive language then why are hexadecimal values not
case-sensitive?

```
int x = 0x21af3;
int y = 0X21AF3;

System.out.println(x==y);
```

It returns true. Can anyone explain why hexadecimal is not case-sensitive?

Comment: Can you explain why you think is should be? But, yes, we can explain: It's because the Java Language Specification says it should not be. [§3.10.1. Integer Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1): *Hexadecimal digits with values 10 through 15 are represented by the ASCII letters a through f or A through F, respectively; each letter used as a hexadecimal digit **may be uppercase or lowercase**.*

Comment: What do you think should be the difference between these two values? Is there a difference between a and A with hex?

Comment: if it was then what value you'll want to put in those variables ?

Comment: What would be the advantage in making it case-sensitive?

Comment: In addition to the other reasons, because hexadecimal is not case sensitive in assembly language or C or C++ or any other language.

Comment: @Andreas, seems beyond the JLS, does that document define the hex symbol set?

Comment: isn't that int datatype you've put in hex? the int type casting make it that way. maybe some documentation would help you better.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Yes, updated comment with link to [§3.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1). Also: [`HexDigit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-HexDigit): *`(one of)`* `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F`

Comment: Also, don't make the mistake of thinking a number's representation is part of a number.  An `int` is just a number.  It is not in hex, decimal, or any other base; it does not have upper or lower case; it doesn't have or not have leading zeroes, etc.  Try `int x=0x21af3; int y=137971; System.out.println(x==y);`.  They are the same number.  It doesn't matter how they're represented in the source.

Comment: how come can you put a hex in an int? sorry for the question.

Comment: @Andreas, that doesn't define the *actual* alphabet although good point. Hex existed far before the JLS. `a` and `A` have the same value. The best any language could do is enforce some unreasonable restriction on case.

Comment: @LKTN please see my previous comment.  You can put any number in an `int` as long as it's between -2147483648 and 2147483647.  _It doesn't matter how the number is represented._

Comment: @LKTN Because it's magic. Oh, you were talking about curses? ;-) Hex is short for "Hexadecimal Representation of a Number". It's still just a number, it's just represented in Base-16, aka Hex.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks Andreas, answer appreciated.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils You don't consider the explicit list `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F` to be a declaration of the hex "alphabet", as used by the Java language?

Comment: @Andreas, I do, but I realize that it's a specification on an existing alphabet. What I believe is hex has a defined alphabet that a given language may choose to constrain; but ultimately everyone familiar with hex "knows" the valid set whether it be upper/lower/mixed.

Comment: @Andreas, in other words, and in support of my original comment, what should be the difference between the cases? There's no other value it can hold so it's a matter of pass/fail vs, for example, sorting a string.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils The JLS explicitly declares what the hex alphabet is, like it explicitly declares so many other things, because what people "know" is so very often wrong. And even if what they know is right, it may only be right elsewhere, not necessarily for Java. Example: Is `i = ++i` well-defined? A C programmer would say no. A Java programmer would say yes. What a C programmer "knows" is not right for Java.

Comment: @Andreas, well, it seems we are now veering off. I don't see that to be an equal example when comparing well-known and well-defined symbols for representations. It may define its own hex "alphabet", but it  had better be in line with what people "know". Would it be reasonable for the JLS to define a *unique* one? Likely not; that is my only point.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I agree. If they defined it differently, there'd be an outcry. Doesn't mean they didn't need to define it anyway, instead of just saying "hex is what everybody knows it to be". That is not a specification. This question is a prime example of everybody *not* knowing. They *had to* define it, and they did. That was my point and why I responded to your *"beyond the JLS"* comment, which is all I was trying to do.

Comment: @Andreas, exactly the reasoning behind recognizing your well-placed point; for all practical purposes they ***had*** to define it for Java code to compile! I see this question as being like *every* other one that takes the form: "Why does 'SomeLanguage' [not] do 'SomeThing'"; it all boils down to the specification which is great for more interesting cases.

Comment: If they had wanted to, they could have forbidden lowercase letters x and a through f. Or the uppercase ones. But really, who would want that and why? I even think the original common usage was small x and capital A through F, but enforcing that would just be confusing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the Java Language Specification says it isn't case-sensitive.

Under [3.10.1. Integer Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1):

> A hexadecimal numeral consists of the leading ASCII characters 0x or 0X followed by one or more ASCII hexadecimal digits interspersed with underscores, and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.
>
> Hexadecimal digits with values 10 through 15 are represented by the ASCII letters a through f or A through F, respectively; **each letter used as a hexadecimal digit may be uppercase or lowercase**.

Comment: Notice that even the `X` in the prefix is case-insensitive.